# using explicit waits autocomplete selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to change this code to something using the explicit waits:

```
class InputAutocompleteElement(InputElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
       driver = obj.driver
       element = self.find_element(driver, self.locator)
       time.sleep(3)
       element.clear()
       time.sleep(1)
       element.send_keys(value)
       time.sleep(3)
       element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

What I'm doing on the above lines is : first , trying to sleep the script for 3 seconds, then clear the textbox, then sleep another second ,then send the string, then sleep another 3 seconds, then send an enter key because this is mandatory to get the name from autocomplete, it's not possible to just type the name ,my problem basically is the page needs needs time to take the value after sending the string and I send the enter key too fast and doesn't work like that, the page needs time to take the value and then send the enter key.

thanks.

Comment: On my opinion, for this example, maybe you can use the [FluentWait](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait) and not the implicit Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely don't need the first two sleeps. The last sleep you should replace with an explicit wait that waits for the autocomplete dropdown to open. Basically you wait for visibility of some element associated with the autocomplete dropdown. You'd have to share a link to the site or post the HTML if you don't know how to locate the autocomplete dropdown. The code below should give you an idea of what to do

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

class InputAutocompleteElement(InputElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
       driver = obj.driver
       element = self.find_element(driver, self.locator)
       element.clear()
       element.send_keys(value)
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "idOfAutocompleteDropdown"))
       element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

You can find more info in the [python docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Thanks JeffC, works your solution, the problem I had was I was pointing to the textbox instead of the autocomplete dropdown, I appreciate your help

Comment: Just one thing I forgot to mention JeffC, I was using the 2 first sleeps because a new window appears on the step before running the script above so that's why I want to wait few seconds until the other window disappears, right now works but it's doing the 2 steps at the same time because the page that is behind is editable even the other window is open but in the future if the page is not editable I would have problems

Comment: A better solution than sleeps is to find an element in the new window and wait for it to be invisible also. That way you only need to wait until it's gone.

Comment: I'm trying with that option using line before the script above:         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Position"]'))), "//div[text()="Position"]" is located in the window that appears on the previous step but not really sure why takes more than 2 seconds , takes around 10 seconds

Comment: If you can't get it figured out after some research and code attempts, I would suggest that you post a new question with all the details.